# Can I recover work from a mypaint session that crashes?

Tags: files

I was saving a piece of work I had worked on for 2 hours.

After I saved it my computer shut off when I got it back up and running I try to open my drawing and this happens.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
 "/usr/share/mypaint/gui/filehandling.py", line 306,
 open_cb(self=<gui.filehandling.FileHandler object>, action=<gtk.Action
 object at 0x8c44054 (GtkAction at 0x89d1dc0)>)
                     dialog.hide()
                     self.open_file(dialog.get_filename().decode('utf-8'))
             finally:   variables: {'decode': (None, []), 'dialog.get_filename': ('local', <built-in method get_filename of
 gtk.FileChooserDialog object at 0x955a43c>), 'self.open_file':
 ('local', <bound method FileHandler.wrapper of
 <gui.filehandling.FileHandler object at 0x8c30dac>>)}   File
 "/usr/share/mypaint/gui/drawwindow.py", line 43,
 wrapper(self=<gui.filehandling.FileHandler object>,
 *args=(u'/home/jen/icyblue.ora',), **kwargs={})
             try:
                 func(self, *args, **kwargs)
             finally:   variables: {'self': ('local', <gui.filehandling.FileHandler object at 0x8c30dac>), 'args': ('local',
 (u'/home/jen/icyblue.ora',)), 'func': ('local', <function open_file at
 0x8bda844>), 'kwargs': ('local', {})}   File
 "/usr/share/mypaint/gui/filehandling.py", line 227,
 open_file(self=<gui.filehandling.FileHandler object>,
 filename=u'/home/jen/icyblue.ora')
             try:
                 self.doc.model.load(filename)
             except document.SaveLoadError, e:   variables: {'self.doc.model.load': ('local', <bound method Document.load of
 <lib.document.Document instance at 0x8c30e2c>>), 'filename': ('local',
 u'/home/jen/icyblue.ora')}   File
 "/usr/share/mypaint/lib/document.py", line 284,
 load(self=<lib.document.Document instance>,
 filename=u'/home/jen/icyblue.ora')
             try:
                 load(filename)
             except gobject.GError, e:   variables: {'load': ('local', <bound method Document.load_ora of <lib.document.Document instance at
 0x8c30e2c>>), 'filename': ('local', u'/home/jen/icyblue.ora')}   File
 "/usr/share/mypaint/lib/document.py", line 450,
 load_ora(self=<lib.document.Document instance>,
 filename=u'/home/jen/icyblue.ora')
             tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp('mypaint')
             z = zipfile.ZipFile(filename)
             print 'mimetype:', z.read('mimetype').strip()   variables: {'zipfile.ZipFile': ('global', <class zipfile.ZipFile at 0x8863b6c>),
 'z': (None, []), 'filename': ('local', u'/home/jen/icyblue.ora')}  
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 710,
 __init__(self=<zipfile.ZipFile instance>, file=u'/home/jen/icyblue.ora', mode='r', compression=0,
 allowZip64=False)
             if key == 'r':
                 self._GetContents()
             elif key == 'w':   variables: {'self._GetContents': ('local', <bound method ZipFile._GetContents of <zipfile.ZipFile
 instance at 0x95629ec>>)}   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line
 744, _GetContents(self=<zipfile.ZipFile instance>)
             try:
                 self._RealGetContents()
             except BadZipfile:   variables: {'self._RealGetContents': ('local', <bound method ZipFile._RealGetContents of <zipfile.ZipFile
 instance at 0x95629ec>>)}   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line
 759, _RealGetContents(self=<zipfile.ZipFile instance>)
             if not endrec:
                 raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"
             if self.debug > 1:   variables: {'BadZipfile': ('global', <class 'zipfile.BadZipfile'>)} BadZipfile: File is not a zip file
```

if there is any way I can retrieve my drawing please assist me for I do not know how to fix this problem, thank you ubuntu forums!

Comment: Why did the computer "shut off"?  You might have thought you saved the file, but it must have still only been partially written when the computer powered down.  It's unlikely that you'll be able to recover the file if this is the case however you could look to see if there's a hidden backup file if the program is set to do timed saves.

Comment: how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see if there's a timed save or backup file there somewhere:

```
ls -a ~/* | grep *icyblue*
```

If there's nothing but the the original file, then you might be out of luck

Save often, and save a lot.  When editing images I often do generational saves, so that if I don't like a subsequent process I can easily go back to the previous save and try again.  This would have also helped you in this case because while you might have lost some work, you would not have lost everything.

To do a generational save, I simply add a number to the end of the filename:

```
filename.png  (original camera image) 
filename1.png (first generation edit) 
filename2.png (second generation edit)
```

and so on.  If I produce subsequent images with different resolutions or for specific purposes then I append that information also.  Yes you can get a lot of files this way, but you'll notice that it saves all of your work right back to the original camera image or draft.

Comment: well it came back in red letters? it says, /home/jen/icyblue.ora

Comment: That would be the same broken file.  You'd be looking for something like '/home/jen/.icyblue.ora.bak' or similar.

Comment: so im screwed and have to start all over?

Comment: I think so.  I don't know of a program that can reliably put a compressed image file back together, and in this case I think the data will have been truncated.  It's gone to the great bit bucket in the sky; sorry dude.

Comment: okay well thanks for your time and help anyways :) I do have the first picture I can re-trace, not too much of a big difference between the two

Answer (score 0):

`.ora` files are OpenRaster format files. MyPaint uses it but also some other programs.

If MyPaint refuses to open the file I would try to open them with an alternative and see if the same happens, you might be lucky and be able to save it in another format or recover your work that way.

Known programs that can use `.ora` files are:

- MyPaint
- GIMP
- Krita
- DrawPile
- Nathive
- Pinta
- XnView

Most of those are open-source and available to be installed in your system. Give them a try before you quit.